# How does FastCGI work on a web server (eg. Apache 2.2+)?

Tags: c++, c, apache, fastcgi

I had a look at the sources of FastCGI (fcgi-2.4.0) and actually there's no sign of fork.
If I'm correct the web server spwans a process for FastCGI module (compiled in it or loaded as a SO/DLL) and handles control of the main socket (the port TCP:80 usually) over to it.

On *nix the FastCGI module "locks" that socket using a file write lock (libfcgi/os_unix.c:989) on the whole file descriptor (the listen socket indeed); this way when new connections income only the FastCGI module is able to process these.
The incoming socket lock is released just before handing over to the HTTP req processing.

As seen as FastCGI module is not multi process/thread (no *internal* usage of fork/pthread_create) I assume the concurrent handling of multiple simultaneous connections is obtained through spwaning from the web server (through OS_SpawnChild) of n FastCGI module processes.
If we spawn, as example, 3 FastCGI processes (Apache calls 3 x OS_SpawnChild), does that mean that we could only have max 3 requests served concurrently?

A) Is my vision of FastCGI way of working correct?

B) If the cost for the OS to spawn a new process/create a connection to local DB could be considered negligible, what are the advantages of FastCGI against an *old fashioned* executable approach?

Thanks,
Ema! :-)

Answer (score 5):

The speed gain from FastCGI over normal CGI is that the processes are persistent. e.g. if you have any database handles to open, you can do them once. Same for any caching.

The main gain comes from not having to create a new php/perl/etc. interpreter each time, which takes a surprising amount of time.

If you wanted to have multiple concurrent connections handled, you do have to have multiple processes FastCGI Processes running. FastCGI is not a way of handling more connections through any kind of special concurrency. It is a way to speed up individual requests, which in turn will allow handling of more requests. But yes you are right, more concurrent requests requires more processes running.

Comment: Not true; FastCGI allows multiple concurrent requests to be handled *with a single thread*. This is [literally the largest benefit to FastCGI, with long lived connections leading to little gain if they do not impliment multiplexing](http://www.nongnu.org/fastcgi/#multiplexing).

Answer (score 4):

FastCGI spawned processes are persistent, they're not killed once the request is handled, instead they're "pooled".

Comment: Arul, thanks, but I already now this...I was asking for more specific answers (A,B). Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

B, yes IF the cost of spawning is zero then legacy CGI would be pretty good.  So if you don't have a lot of hits plain old CGI is fine, run with it.  The point of fast cgi is doing things that benefit from a lot of persistent storage, or structures that have to be built BEFORE you can get your work done, like running queries against large databases, where you want to leave the DB libraries in memory instead of having to reload the whole shebang every time you want to run a query.

It matters when you have LOTS OF HITS.

Comment: Untrue; CGI cannot cache, which means any storage must be reloaded (access to a database can easily be slower than a simple C program loading). CGI also cannot multiplex (which means to get concurrency you need multiple processes). These two benefits are by far more important than the cost of spawning; furthermore, it is [basically no programming cost to make a CGI module work with FastCGI, and with careful code, it's trivial to make a FastCGI module load correctly as CGI or FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fastcgi-prog-guide/ch2c.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed,

so as seen (A) is ok, now what about (B)?
If I'm talking about executables (properly compiled C/C++ programs, not scripts like perl/php/...), and if we consider the process spwan cost and DB new connection cost negligible, then this approach (FastCGI) is just a *sort of small gain* compared to plain CGI executables?

I mean, given that Linux is very fast in spawning (forking) a process and if the DB is running locally (eg. same host MySQL), the time it takes to start a new executable and connect to the DB is practically 0. In this case, without nothing to be interpreted, only Apache C/C++ modules would be faster than this.

Using the FastCGI approach then you are even more vulnerable to mem leaks as seen as the process isn't forked/restarted every time...At this point, if you have to develop your CGI in C/C++ wouldn't be better to use *old school* CGI and/or Apache C/C++ modules directly?

Again, I'm not talking about scripts (perl/php/...), I'm talking about compiled CGI.

Thanks again,
Cheers, Ema! :-)

Comment: The cost of forking is only one part of running PHP through CGI. Once the process is forked you still have to load the PHP executable into memory and do what ever initialize is required at startup.  Also opening a fresh connection to the database is much more expensive than reusing and existing one.

Comment: Guys, thanks for the answers, but I'm not talking about perl/php scripts, but about compiled EXECUTABLES (C++ source code compiled against cgicc library for example)...I don't know how to write it more clearly anymore...

Comment: Absolutely not; FastCGI can support multiplexing, which means it can handle a multitude of connections at once. If properly programmed, this means you can form a pipeline, where new connections are never starved by database connection opening, which never delay returning results *immediately* from database queries. The average latency of your FastCGI module can be **orders of magnitude lower than CGI**.